# Magento 2.2x Multiple Product Pricing/Quantity

Tags: magento2.2, product-prices

I am building a website for a client that has multiple brick-and-mortar locations and I need to set up products with different prices (both retail and MAP) and quantities for each product based on the location a customer picks from the Magento site. I'm looking for advice on the best way to set this up.

For example, I have 10 physical stores that sell the same 100 products, but each product has its own pricing and quantities. I want the customer to pick a store and have Magento use the information for that store. I have the pricing and quantity information stored in a separate CSV file.

I don't know if there's an existing module someone has already created to do this, if I need to set up separate Magento stores (one for each physical store), or if I need to have something custom written.

Answer (score 0):

You can set price per website basis.

you need to go to,

> System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog Price Scope.

Then in the tab "**Price**", set price scope to "**Website**" instead of **global**.

Different price for store view, many extension available. Here is some example:

1. https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-view-pricing.html
2. http://bsscommerce.com/magento-multistore-pricing.html

Comment: Does this mean I have to build a store and/or website in Magento for each physical store in order to switch between the scopes?

Comment: You have to build one store and for each physical store a store-view and assign the quantities and prices to that specific store-view. Another method would be seperate stores for each physical store - That way you dont have to use any extensions

Answer (score 0):

Good day, sounds like an interesting project. It should be possible to set the price and quantity attribute from "global" or "website" to "storeview" and use the different quantities and prices that way.

---

**For Quantity**
You can take a look at the attributes by accessing the Backend and navigating to `stores / Attribtues / Product` and search for `Quantity`. Change the `Scope` to `Storeview` at `Advanced Attribute Properties`.

**For Price**
The `price` attribute cant be changed to storeview by default so you have to use an extension for that - There are multiple out there, just search for `Magento 2 Product price per storeview` and choose a fitting one.

I hope I could help you a bit with that project.

Comment: Does this mean I have to build a store and/or website in Magento for each physical store in order to switch between the scopes?

Comment: You have to build one store and for each physical store a store-view and assign the quantities and prices to that specific store-view. Another method would be seperate stores for each physical store - That way you dont have to use any extensions